# Создание временной строки в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!

Делаю онлайн игру. В таблице enemy занесены враги. Если играет несколько игроков одновременно, то получается, что удары в момент времени по врагу наносят несколько человек и вместо 1 жизни, например отнимается 3, т.к. запись врага одна и уникальна.

Беру параметры врага из базы:

```
  $resultenemy = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT name,current_health,max_health,photo,exp,min_strenght,max_strenght,drop3 FROM enemy WHERE id='".$enemyid."'");
while ($enemy= mysqli_fetch_array($resultenemy)) {
    $enemyname.=$enemy['name'];
    $current_healthenemy.=$enemy['current_health'];
    $max_healthenemy.=$enemy['max_health'];
    $photoenemy.=$enemy['photo'];
    $expenemy.=$enemy['exp'];
    $minstrenghtenemy.=$enemy['min_strenght'];
    $maxstrenghtenemy.=$enemy['max_strenght'];
    $dropenemy.=$enemy['drop3'];

}
```

Можно ли как-то при входе в бой mysql запросом создать копию врага с уникальным id префиксом и удалить строку с врагом после боя?

Comment: Можно, почему нет.... делайте отдельную таблицу и вперед....

Comment: Каждый игрок бьёт свою копию врага, независимо? если так, то враг - это атрибут игрока, а таблица врагов - это таблица шаблонов, а не экземпляров.